# Why does this highlighter not always work?

Tags: javascript, css

Why is my highlighter so buggy? To start, select the text and then choose one of the colors to make the selection bold. But, sometimes it doesn't do it and sometimes it does. Also, I only want that text to be bold not every instance of that same phrase. For example, if you highlight *Hello* all the Hellos will be bold. I only want the Hello selected to be bolded. **How do I fix this problem?**

```js
 $("#actual_verse").mouseup(function() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    
    if (/\S/.test(text)) {
      new_text = "<div id='color_div'>"+text+"</div>";
      
          $(".boxes").click(function() {
  var title = $(this).attr("title");
  var reg = new RegExp(text,"g");
   $('#actual_verse').html($('#actual_verse').html().replace(reg,'<strong>'+text+'</strong>'));
  document.getElementById('tooltip').style.display = 'none';
});
  
        
   // Tool Tip
  
var ele = document.getElementById('tooltip');
var sel = window.getSelection();
var rel1= document.createRange();
rel1.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal1'));
var rel2= document.createRange();
rel2.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal2'));
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
        debugger;
        var r = sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
        var rb1 = rel1.getBoundingClientRect();
        var rb2 = rel2.getBoundingClientRect();
        ele.style.top = (r.bottom - rb2.top)*100/(rb1.top-rb2.top) + 'px'; //this will place ele below the selection
        ele.style.left = (r.left - rb2.left)*100/(rb1.left-rb2.left) + 'px'; //this will align the right edges together

        //code to set content

        ele.style.display = 'block';
    }
});

  // End of Tool Tip
  
  }
  
    
  });
```

```css
/* Tool Kit */

#tooltip {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    border:grey solid 1px;
    background: #373737;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
#cal1{
    position:absolute;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    overflow:none;
    z-index:-100;
}
#cal2{
    position:absolute;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:none;
    z-index:-100;
}

.boxes {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

#blue_box {
  background: #AAF6FF;
}

#green_box {
  background: #D6FFAA;
}

#orange_box {
  background: #FFBF98;
}

#purple_box {
  background: #D7D5FC;
}

#red_box {
  background: #FF9B9F;
}

#yellow_box {
  background: #FFF8AA;
}


/* End of Tool Kit */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='actual_verse'> Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here </span>
<div id='cal1'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='cal2'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='tooltip'> <div id='blue_box' class='boxes' title='Blue'></div> <div id='green_box' class='boxes' title='Green'></div> <div id='orange_box' class='boxes' title='Orange'></div> <div id='purple_box' class='boxes' title='Purple'></div> <div id='red_box' class='boxes' title='Red'></div> </div> <br> <br>
```

Comment: Just what I've observed: Your replace script replaces *all instances* of the highlighted text, not merely the selected instance. You run replace over the entire text string, not the selection. And the boldface fails if the selection contains something which is already bold. Presumably because the selection becomes an HTML string due to unseen `<strong>` tags, not merely text.

Comment: @Scott Your right. What is the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: Using innerHTML will destroy events and triggers  regeneration of the DOM. Use e.g. [mark.js](https://markjs.io) instead

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting problem. Try use Rangy. [Download zip file from Git](https://github.com/timdown/rangy). Be careful with messing up with Range and Selection on your own before calling MyHighlight.toggleSelection() (when calling it, make sure the selection is visible in the browser).

Here is simplified version (changes made to "script" tags, also "*.highlight" style is added).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rangy-master/external/log4javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rangy-master/src/core/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rangy-master/src/core/dom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rangy-master/src/core/domrange.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rangy-master/src/core/wrappedrange.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rangy-master/src/core/wrappedselection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rangy-master/src/modules/rangy-classapplier.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var MyHighlight;

    rangy.addInitListener(function(rangy) {
        MyHighlight = rangy.createClassApplier("highlight", true);
    });

    $( document ).ready(function() {


            $(".boxes").mousedown(function() {
                    MyHighlight.toggleSelection();
                    document.getElementById('tooltip').style.display = 'none';

            });

            $("#actual_verse").mouseup(function() {


                        var ele = document.getElementById('tooltip');
                        ele.style.display = 'block';


      });



    });





</script>
<style>

        /* Tool Kit */

    #tooltip {
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
        border:grey solid 1px;
        background: #373737;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    #cal1{
        position:absolute;
        height:0px;
        width:0px;
        top:100px;
        left:100px;
        overflow:none;
        z-index:-100;
    }
    #cal2{
        position:absolute;
        height:0px;
        width:0px;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        overflow:none;
        z-index:-100;
    }

    .boxes {
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 2px;
      position: relative;
      top: 3px;
    }

    #blue_box {
      background: #AAF6FF;
    }

    #green_box {
      background: #D6FFAA;
    }

    #orange_box {
      background: #FFBF98;
    }

    #purple_box {
      background: #D7D5FC;
    }

    #red_box {
      background: #FF9B9F;
    }

    #yellow_box {
      background: #FFF8AA;
    }

        /* Tool Kit */

    #tooltip {
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
        border:grey solid 1px;
        background: #373737;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    #cal1{
        position:absolute;
        height:0px;
        width:0px;
        top:100px;
        left:100px;
        overflow:none;
        z-index:-100;
    }
    #cal2{
        position:absolute;
        height:0px;
        width:0px;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        overflow:none;
        z-index:-100;
    }

    .boxes {
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 2px;
      position: relative;
      top: 3px;
    }

    #blue_box {
      background: #AAF6FF;
    }

    #green_box {
      background: #D6FFAA;
    }

    #orange_box {
      background: #FFBF98;
    }

    #purple_box {
      background: #D7D5FC;
    }

    #red_box {
      background: #FF9B9F;
    }

    #yellow_box {
      background: #FFF8AA;
    }


    *.highlight {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color:#ff0000;
    }


</style>
</head>
<body>
<span id='actual_verse'> Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here </span>
<div id='cal1'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='cal2'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='tooltip'> <div id='blue_box' class='boxes' title='Blue'></div> <div id='green_box' class='boxes' title='Green'></div> <div id='orange_box' class='boxes' title='Orange'></div> <div id='purple_box' class='boxes' title='Purple'></div> <div id='red_box' class='boxes' title='Red'></div> </div> <br> <br>
</body>
</html>
```